# Sending multiple files to webdav server in one request

Tags: webdav

I want to send to webdav server a 100 files in one request. I'm getting list of messages, then I creating binary body parts of them. This is my code which gets me 301 http error response code. When I send one file it's working but expected behaviour is to send parts of files. And I want it to be created one file by one on the server, is it possible?

```
 CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPut httpPost = new HttpPut("http://localhost:8888/webdav"); // I also tried with / at the end

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        messages.forEach(m -> {
            builder.addBinaryBody("file", new File(Paths.get(m.getPath()).toAbsolutePath().toString()),
                    ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, m.getFileName() + ".encryptedByAes");
            builder.addBinaryBody("file", new File(Paths.get(m.getAesPath()).toAbsolutePath().toString()),
                    ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, m.getFileName() + ".aes");
        });

        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
        httpPost.setEntity(multipart);

        UsernamePasswordCredentials creds
                = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test", "test");
        httpPost.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, httpPost, null));

        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HTTP_OK) {
            throw new WebDavException("Error while executing request to webdav server with messages");
        }
        client.close();
```

Comment: Sending multiple files in one request is not a standard WebDAV feature. It's possible that your specific server has *some* way to handle this, but it's hard to say without more detail. One question comes to mind is, why not multiple requests?

Comment: @Evert because it will be probably a lot of files to send, maybe thousands and it's about performance. I think sending thousands of request will be less efficient than sending parts of eg. 100 files at once and reduce amount of requests. I know that I can make zip but that's not expected result. Webdav server comes from users and it can be provided by them so I don't have possibility to handle this on server side.

Comment: So, unfortunately you don't really have an option here. WebDAV does not have an out-of-the-box way to combine multiple requests. There is definitely some overhead per request, but perhaps not as much as you think. Make sure your client supports HTTP/2, if it's available it will definitely give you a performance boost.

Comment: you can instead create multiple processes, each one uploading one image at a time. this should speed things up