# Upload multiple files with pyCurl

Tags: python, upload, pycurl

I am using pyCurl to upload a single file to a WebDAV server. The content is stored in a base64 string.

I am using this codesnipped:

```
def fileupload(url, filename, filedata, upload_user, upload_pw):
    filedata = base64.b64decode(filedata).decode('ascii', 'ignore')

    # Initialize pycurl
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    url = url + filename
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    c.setopt(pycurl.UPLOAD, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.READFUNCTION, StringIO(filedata).read)
    c.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5)
    c.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 20)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2)
    c.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, "ca.pem")
    c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, upload_user + ":" + upload_pw)

    # Set size of file to be uploaded.
    filesize = len(filedata)
    c.setopt(pycurl.INFILESIZE, filesize)

    # Start transfer
    logPes.debug('Uploading file %s to url %s' % (filename, url))
    try:
        c.perform()

        # Check result of transfer
        if c.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE) == 201:
            c.close()
            logPes.info('Fileupload successful')
            return True
        else:
            logPes.error('Fileupload NOT successful. Error code {0}.'.format(c.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)))
            c.close()
            return False
    
    except pycurl.error as error:
        logPes.error('Fileupload: {0}'.format(error.args[1]))
        return False
```

For uploading multiple files can I call this function multiple times. But then a new connection for each upload is opened and closed. Is it possible to upload multiple files with pyCurl with the same connection?

Perhaps the `pycurl.CurlMulti()` function is the right one for this. Unfortunatly I can not find information if the "multi" function is carried out in the same connection. Is it running serial or asyncron? I am interessted in an upload one file after the another with the same open connection to the http server to reduce the load (the server is a little bit wonky).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could build a list of file data, which can be uploaded in one go, if you know which files has to be uploaded.
`form_contents = [("file", (pycurl.FORM_FILE, file_path)) for file_path in files]

# Set the form data
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPOST, form_contents)`

Comment: Thanks! Is this working with my base64 file content? I mention this because I am using the `pycurl.READFUNCTION` option to read directly from the decoded base64 data.

Comment: Looks like I have to use the `FORM_BUFFER` and `FORM_BUFFERPTR` options. I will test this and give you some feedback...

Comment: I am orientated myself on the example on pycurl.io. Unfortunatly I am getting a 405. Looks at the moment, that the server does not support uploading by POST, just by PUT?

Comment: If its not your own server, and you can add the corresponding http method. Can you try with put?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can not modify the server. It is a blackbox for us.

For my understanding, setting `c.setopt(pycurl.UPLOAD, 1)` set method to PUT? So, I can not use your codesnipped because it is using html form which has to use POST method?

Comment: you can try:
c.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT")

Comment: Still a 405... strange...

Comment: The modified codesnipped:

`c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url) # Without filename

    c.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT") 
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPOST, [
        ('fileupoad', (
            pycurl.FORM_BUFFER, 'SAMPLE.MPF',
            pycurl.FORM_BUFFERPTR, 'TESTDATA',
        )),
    ])`

Comment: One important note... its a WebDAV server... I modified my post....

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment [Sending multiple files to webdav server in one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530697/sending-multiple-files-to-webdav-server-in-one-request#comment108844475_61530697) I came to the conclusion, that multiple upload in one request is not possible with WebDAV. I went now for a solution by changing to httpv2 for speed up the process. At the moment it is working fine for us. If I found an alternative to reduce the amount of connections to the WebDAV server I will add this here.